# NeoVim Fugitive Plugin Gpush Locking Up

Tags: git, vim, neovim, vim-fugitive

Using NeoVim I am having problems with the `:Gpush` command locking up the editor.  Does anyone have a work around for this problem?

Comment: It should be noted that this is no longer an issue in new versions of Neovim.
The command `Git push` works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that your problem is that you need to manually type username/password from your shell when you're pushing to github. I don't think that GPush was designed to allow for that. this probably solves your problem

```
:te git push
```

you'll likely see a terminal window on your screen asking for username/password. You'll need to type `i` to enter insert mode on your terminal and should be good to go.

Comment: Worked great for me.  Is there any way to automatically put the cursor in the location to enter the username?

Comment: I guess that `autocmd TermOpen * startinsert` should do the job

Answer (score 0):

fugitive's push will work synchronously on nvim. from the fugitive help file

```
                                                *fugitive-:Gpush*
:Gpush [args]           Invoke git-push, load the results into the |quickfix|
                        list, and invoke |:cwindow| to reveal any errors.
                        |:Dispatch| is used if available for asynchronous
                        invocation.
```

the thing is that there isn't a dispatch function on nvim. You could run

```
!git push &
```

but this will prevent you from seeing the output of the command(which is bad cuz: what if the fit push failed?)

Here is a replacement function for fugitive's GPush that solved for me, might be useful for you too(put it in your init.vim). It harnesses nvim's async job-control `:h job-control` and shows you the output in the preview window `:h preview-window`

```
function! s:shell_cmd_completed(...) dict
    wincmd P
    setlocal modifiable
    call append(line('$'), self.shell)
    call append(line('$'), '########################FINISHED########################')
    call append(line('$'), self.pid)
    call jobstop(self.pid)
    normal! G
    setlocal nomodifiable
    wincmd p
endfunction

function! s:JobHandler(job_id, data, event) dict
    let str = join(a:data)
    wincmd P
    call append(line('$'), str)
    normal! G
    wincmd p
endfunction

function! GitPush()
    let s:shell_tmp_output = tempname()
    execute 'pedit '.s:shell_tmp_output
    wincmd P
    wincmd J
    setlocal modifiable
    setlocal nobuflisted
    nnoremap <buffer>q :bd<cr>
    wincmd p
    let s:callbacks = {
    \ 'on_stdout': function('s:JobHandler'),
    \ 'on_stderr': function('s:JobHandler'),
    \ 'on_exit': function('s:shell_cmd_completed'),
    \ 'shell': 'git push'
    \ }
    let pid = jobstart('git push', s:callbacks)
    let s:callbacks.pid = pid
endfunction

command! GitPush call GitPush()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I attempted to put this into my init.vim file.  I made a push to a repository and running the :GitPush command also locked up my nvim terminal.  Could it  be something to do with the terminal I am using?

Comment: what terminal are you using? this is very strange indeed. What happens if you just run `:call jobstart('git push')`? does this also lock your terminal?

Comment: Yes that command locks up my terminal as well.  I use the default Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: what version of neovim are you using? What about `!git push` or `!git push &`? Are you able to push from your terminal outside of vim?

Comment: Yes I am able to push from outside of nvim.  My current version is v0.2.2.

Comment: what about `!git push` or `!git push &`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164985/discussion-between-sudavid4-and-joseph-fehrman).